# How to search for letter in string in SQL

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i have table like below

```
ID  |  Place
-------------
0   | BANGALORE
1   | BEGUR
```

Now in this table, i need a query which returns the rows when i search like 'BR'. BR terms are present in both rows, is there a way to search string like this?

Comment: How is BR present in the second row? So do you want to select a row if even at least one letter matches?

Comment: B and R are present in both rows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LIKE` operator. This will return rows which has the word `'B'` before `'R'` in any position

```
select * from tablename where Place like '%B%R%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Wildcards

```
SELECT * WHERE place LIKE "%B%R%"
```

**Reference**

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: Keep in mind I gave you a reference to the wildcards so you can manipulate the code I gave you to fix your problem.  Instead of down voting my answer go read the article.  Stop being lazy.

Comment: regardless if it's correct or not it addressed the issue at hand.  Just because I didn't get 100% what he asked doesn't mean that he couldn't have manipulated the code I gave him to solve his problem.  I gave him sample code and told him wildcards will do this.  Then I provided a wildcard reference.  I don't feel bad for anybodies laziness.  Funny how people want to be spoon fed...when you are asking us for help.

Comment: If you give a **wrong** answer, expect downvotes. If you give it **correct**, you **might** expect upvotes. It's not a matter of laziness. Anyway, +1. The answer is **STILL WRONG**, I suggest you adding **FROM table_name**. I see someone already noticed that and downvoted...

Answer (score 1):

This query will find the strings which contains the letters 'B' and 'R' any where in the string!!

```
select Place from table_name where Place like "%B%" and Place like "%R%";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @VINAYDANARADDI Pls accept the answer if your problem is solved!

Comment: Why do you use **2** Likes, when you could use just **1**?

Comment: @DerGolem Ya I agree! But my query works good if the order of letters  does'nt matter (i.e. BR and RB).Since he does not mention about any order I posted this answer!

Comment: Good point. I noticed that both the places in the example also share **G** and **E**. With the **G** being in the sequence **BGR**, while the **E** is "out of place"...

Comment: @DerGolem Correct! you got it!

Answer (score -1):

It seems simple enough following my understanding.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Place LIKE 'BR%';
```

Recommendation: [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

Comment: This only looks for words starting with "BR". Like **Br**itain, **Br**ighton, **Br**oadway, ... Won't match **B**angalo**r**e nor **B**egu**r**